# PyAudio example syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyaudio

http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#examples

Attempting to run the above PyAudio example with 'python test.py c:\test.wav' from the cmd line returns:

```
File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
  wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
File "C:\Python27\lib\wave.py", line 511, in open
  return Wave_read(f)
File "C:\Python27\lib\wave.py", line 160, in __init__
  f = __builtin__.open(f, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\test.wav'
```

I've tried with multiple audio files and locations.  What am I missing?

Windows 7 64-bit
Python 2.7

Comment: What files and locations? It's complaining it can't find your file. Where are you putting it?

Comment: I've tried a few locations.  Currently I have it at the root of the C drive for simplicity.